# Should neural net training data reflect the "proportions" to be expected in real data

Tags: classification, data-mining, neural-networks

I am currently training a NN classifier on synthetic data generated from a model of real data, and this synthetic data is uniformly generated across the range of values expected in the real data. However, even a cursory inspection of the real data shows that a smaller range of values within the broader range occur much more frequently. For example, assuming a range of 1 to 10 inclusive, 4s, 5s, 6s and 7s occur more than 1s and 10s, and 2s, 3s, 8s and 9s lie in between, in terms of frequency of occurrence.

My question is: should the distribution of the created training data be similar to that of the real data? My concern is that by having uniformly distributed training data I may be inadvertently over-weighting the importance of the less frequently occurring data and correspondingly under-weighting the most commonly occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right.

The loss you optimize when training a neural network is basically the sum over your some function of the rows in your training set. That loss acts as a proxy called the "empirical distribution" for the true underlying distribution which you do not have access to.

However, it might not hurt: if you have lots of data (since you generate it) you can train a really large network. In the limit, you have an infinitely large network with infinite training data - and the network can just remember all inputs and thus predict them perfectly. This sounds rather theoretical, but I have had cases where some kind of fixing the empirical distribution to somewhat resemble the true distribution more (because of prior knowedge) have not helped at all. Actually, the error on held out test data was roughly the same for both training sets.

So if it hurts your specific training problem depends on the data and the problem.